# pandas to change the colum value withoutchanging the format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Excel sheet with 10000 Rows.
I have to change the value of a Colum5 based on value of Colum2 and update the excel sheet.

I am able to change the values using:

```
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_excel('part2.xlsx')
count=0

while (count<10000):
     if df['Grade'][count] == 'A' :
         #df.loc[df['Grade'][count]] = 'Good'
         df['Grade'][count] = 'Good'
         print(count)
         print(df['Grade'][count])
     count=count+1

df.to_excel('temp.xlsx')
```

The issue with this is as I am writing to a new Excel sheet all the formatting is gone.
I want to achieve the same thing in the same excelsheet so that format is not removed.

2) is there any use in keeping the df.loc here?

Answer (score 0):

By using `.loc`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Grade':['A','B','C','A','D']})
df.loc[(df.Grade=='A')&(df.index<3),'Grade']='Good'
df
Out[489]: 
  Grade
0  Good
1     B
2     C
3     A
4     D
```

More info

```
(df.Grade=='A')&(df.index<3)
Out[296]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: Grade, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thankyou , I di dnot get how this loc is working here?  dont I need to write to excel? can you please explain bit more

Comment: @user pandas dataframe is base on index, first we get the row need to change by this Boolean index getting the all A before certain index.
 (df.Grade=='A')&(df.index<3), then we block the top 3 (in your real case should be 10000), then we apply the change, also add more info

Comment: when we write the frame to the excelsheet the formating will be lost. As shown in question can u please let me understand how to achieve this